# How redirect urls with special url?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-redirect

I want to redirect this type url to my home page

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?showuser=
```

to

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/
```

Can I do this with .htaccess? How to do it. I tried this but works nothing.

```
redirectMatch 301 /index.php?showuser= http://www.mywebsite.com
```

And

```
RedirectMatch 301 /index.php\?showuser\= http://www.mywebsite.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't match against the query string in the `RedirectMatch` regex. You need to use mod_rewrite and the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^showuser=
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: @RockySena replace the `/?` with `/demo?`. The `/` in the rule's target is just the "root" path.

Comment: Thank u its working... can u tell me what should i do if there is a space in url and want to redirect it

Comment: @RockySena replace the space with a `%20`. or escape it with a `\`: `/foo\ bar`.

Answer (score 0):

Neither `Redirect` or `RedirectMatch` can match the query string. The `?` in `RedirectMatch` actually means "the previous character 0 or 1 times", and would be matched against "index.php". Please note that you are not using the dot correctly too.

You can solve this by using mod_rewrite. Make sure that it is enabled, and that you allow override of FileInfo. Then use the following directives:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^showuser=$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [R,L]
```

Change `[R]` to `[R=301]` if you wish to make the redirect permanent after testing everything works as expected.